# Combine sequence of positive integers into one unique integer

Tags: algorithm, math, unique

So I've got a list of positive integers and I want to combine all elements into one unique integer. But I am only able to use basic arithmetic (+, -, *, /).

The result should have the semantics of a hash for the input sequence. So no other sequence should be able to produce it.

Any suggestions how I could tackle this problem?

Comment: But, other than perfect hash functions, hashes have the property that multiple sequences *can* produce the same hash output.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yeah I'm aware of this. So I tried to make it clear that collisions should not occur in my problem.

Comment: What is the range of input numbers?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur they are all positive without a upper bound.

Comment: Okay, so the output hash also has no upper bound. Right?

Comment: Are you sure there is no upper bound xD ?  

https://www.universetoday.com/153035/there-are-6x1080-bits-of-information-in-the-observable-universe/

Comment: Maybe you mean "collisions should be highly unlikely"?

Comment: `semantics of a hash` is **not** `no other sequence should be able to produce [the same value]` - a good *hash function* makes collisions unlikely as can be. For "hashing" values from a (semi-)static set one can use [perfect hash functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). Difficulty/infeasibility to produce one more sequence with a given hash value is one requirement for [Cryptographic hash functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: For *(multi-)sets* of positive integers, there's starting with 1 and, for each element *k*, multiplying by the *k*th prime. The product contains no clue to the order of factors.

Comment: You have a list of integers. Logically, the list is integers with a separator character. Hence, your list is equivalent to a single base 11 integer, counting the separator as a base 11 digit, value 10. Assuming you want the result in base 10, then convert the base 11 integer to base 10. As others have pointed out, this 'hash' can potentially get very large since it is of unlimited size.

Comment: Can you provide some additional information that makes this an answerable question? Otherwise, it should be closed.

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508215/store-non-binary-values-into-a-unique-integer/73514054

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting "hash" to mean that the output domain is bounded, it's not possible to "hash" an unbounded input sequence to a unique output. Those numbers can only be compressed so much without losing information.

If this were possible, compression ratios for any digital information could approach infinity.