# Store non-binary values into a unique integer

Tags: optimization, storage, bit, radix

In **8 bits** we can store **8 numbers** from `0` to `1` each. We can also say that we can store **8 different** piece of data in a range from `0` to `255`.

```
 0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1  → 8 different piece of data
  ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓
[bit] [bit] [bit] [bit] [bit] [bit] [bit] [bit] → 8 bits total
```

If instead of storing `0` or `1` we need to store `0`, `1` or `2`, then we will end up using **more bits**, of course. In this condition, by the way, we can store `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`. However, this is beyond what I need but technically it will use the same amount of data space.

```
 0/1/2   0/1/2   0/1/2   0/1/2  → 4 different piece of data (expectative)
0/1/2/3 0/1/2/3 0/1/2/3 0/1/2/3 → 4 different piece of data (too much for me)
   ↓       ↓       ↓       ↓
[2bits] [2bits] [2bits] [2bits] → 8 bits total
```

We can agree that we are "losing" storage capacity. The solution is to do a **radix conversion** (*I don't know if that's the right term*) using the **numerical base of 3**, this way we will achieve the objective of storing exclusively `0`, `1` or `2`, and in the same 8 bits we can store more information (*and, to be honest, I don't know how the bits organize themselves for this to work*).

**Examples:**

```
00000₃ → int 0
01212₃ → int 50
11111₃ → int 121
12121₃ → int 151
22222₃ → int 242 (max)
```

In this conversion, we were able to store **5 pieces of information** composed of `0`, `1` or `2`, instead of just 4. And there's still a "space" left, and that's what I'd like to talk about.

I was wondering if there is any way to store **mixed base** data instead of **fixed base** (eg. 3, as exemplified above). To be clearer, supposing that I wanted to store two pieces of data composed of `0`, `1` or `2` each, and one piece of data composed of a number between `0` and `8`. In binary, and still limited to `256`, we can do it as follows:

```
 0/1/2   0/1/2    0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8  → 3 piece of different data
   ↓       ↓              ↓
[2bits] [2bits] [      4 bits      ] → 8 bits total
```

But, it seems to me that we have empty "spaces" left again, since it doesn't seem to me to be using the full capacity possible in **8 bits**, and maybe it's still possible to add more data if we use number base conversion instead.

**The problem is:** I don't know how to handle the data in this way, in a way to reliably merge and split it again.

**In the real world:** I need to transfer a lot of data that uses very little information (eg numbers *0 to 2*, *0 to 5*, *0 to 10*, etc.). And I'm currently doing bitwise snapping of this data. And in my case, any optimized byte is a very nice gain (if this is really possible, maybe there is a 20~40% data saving).

I understand that it might consume more processing on rebasing, merge and split conversions, but that won't be an issue, because this processing will be done on the client side (*merge when sending* and *split when receiving*), and the server manages the same data already optimized (no additional processing).

--

**Possible solutions:**

Let's imagine that I have a **set of three numbers** that can be `0`, `1` or `2`, and **another set of three numbers** that can go from `0` to `8` (so it is 9 possibilities each). The goal is to merge all these numbers into **a single integer** (which should use about **2 bytes** at best current method).

**Solution 1:** each number being stored in a single complete byte:

```
byte A from 0 to 2
byte B from 0 to 2
byte C from 0 to 2
byte D from 0 to 8
byte E from 0 to 8
byte F from 0 to 8
```

**Problem:** it will be necessary to consume **6 bytes** to store these **6 numbers**.

**Solution 2:** storage through **bits**:

```
2 bits to store A
2 bits to store B
2 bits to store C
4 bits to store F
4 bits to store G
4 bits to store H
6 unused bits to complete the last byte
```

**Problems:** in addition to **2 bits** being "more than necessary" to store numbers from `0` to `2` (A, B and C), and same for **4 bits** from `0` to `8`, we will use a total of **3 bytes** and still have 6 "dead" (unused) bits at end to complete the last byte.

**Solution 3:** Separate into **two sets** and convert their respective bases individually:

```
A, B and C to base 3 consumes 1 byte
D, E and F to base 9 consumes 2 bytes
```

**Problem:** despite being a great solution at the moment (and despite the example above, in more complex situations it can be more optimized than solution 2), and that's what I'm using, I believe there's a lot of "left over" space in this union, and maybe it's still possible to squeeze everything into **2 bytes** only.

For example, the conversion of 222₃ consumes up to 5 bits, which means that in this byte we still have 3 unused bits. The 888₉ conversion consumes 10 bits. This makes me see the possibility of using only 15 bits with only 1 unused bit (2 bytes).

Then we come to the next solution.

**Solution 4:** move the bits to further optimize space:

```
higher bits stores A, B and C
lower bits stores D, E and F
```

Example:

```
[5 bits of numbers of base 3] +
[10 bits of numbers of base 9] +
[1 unused bit]
```

**Problem:** currently this solution is even better than the one I am currently using. However, I still see a possibility to improve in situations where more information may be available through number base conversion and union.

Comment: int number = 0; int multi = 1; number = number.add(multi.multiply(currentValue)); multi = multi.multiply(currentCountPossibleValues));

Comment: Mixed radix conversion is about as easy as fixed radix conversion. You can even take into account different probabilities for each value, is that something you're interested in? In that case the final size would not be constant, you would get small output in more likely cases and larger output in less likely cases.

Comment: Use `[2bits]` to store `0/1/2`, then we have one empty "space" left. Then repeat it 3 times, we get three empty "space" left. Then use three empty space to store `0/1/2`. Actually what I want to say is that we can make radix bigger enough and let empty `spaces` less engouh.

Comment: @TThoEinthausend I cannot understand what do you mean, actually.

Comment: @harold the resulting size should be up to a certain specified limit, which is compatible with the amount of information I need to store. For example: I might need to store five sets of `0`/`1`/`2` and five sets of `0` to `10`. Maybe this takes 3 or 4 bytes, but it's better than 5 (if I were to use "full bits" method).

Comment: @mariolu the problem is that to store `0`/`1`/`2` in 2 bits we will not have, in practice, a space left over. It's strange to think like this, but in practice we can store `0`/`1`/`2`/`3` in the same 2 bits, but not necessarily left over if we reduce it to 1 possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pack your values in the following way:

Example:

possible values for

```
a = [0,2] -> 3 states
b = [0,2] -> 3 states
c = [0,8] -> 9 states
```

lets assume you have following values

```
a := 1
b := 2
c := 8
```

than you can calculate the final number the following way

```
int number = 0; 
int multi = 1; 
number = number.add(multi.multiply(a));
multi = multi.multiply(3)); 
number = number.add(multi.multiply(b));
multi = multi.multiply(3));
number = number.add(multi.multiply(c));
```

`number` holds now your packed numbers

to unpack you just need todo

```
a = number.mod(3)
number = number.divide(3)

b = number.mod(3)
number = number.divide(3)

c = number.mod(9)
```

Comment: Cool, looks like a viable solution. I'll test it here and get back with the result. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with unpacking process. Following your example, the packing worked perfectly (where multipliers `M1 = 1`, `M2 = 3`, `M3 = 27`). So number is (step-by-step based on `A = 1`, `B = 2`, `C = 8` example) `N1 = M1 * A = 1`, `N2 = N1 + M2 * B = 7` and `N3 = N2 + M3 * C = 223`. So the packed number is `223`, right? Now for unpacking is a bit confuse, because `A = MOD(223, 3) = 1` (right), `B = MOD(223/3, 3) = MOD(74.333, 3) = 2.333` (?) and `C = MOD(223/3/3, 9) = MOD(24.778, 3) = 6.7778` (?). Can you identify my error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ```N3 = 223``` is correct
```A = 1``` is correct

\-> ```N1 = 233/3 = 74```

```B = N1 % 9 = 2```

\-> ```N2 = 74/9 = C = 8```

Comment: ```N1 = 223/3 = 74```